# How to improve this function to avoid indexing duplicate documents on Elasctisearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, duplicates

how could i improve my function to insert the id of my dataframe in the "_id" of Elasticsearch document to handle duplicates?.

**Dataframe structure**

```
print(df.info())

#   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------             --------------  -----
 0   id                 412 non-null    object
 1   email_address      412 non-null    object
 2   first_name         412 non-null    object
 3   last_name          412 non-null    object
```

**The funtion to convert to an elasticsearch compatible format**

```
def to_elastic_json(df, index_name):
            import json
            for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
                yield ('{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s"}}'% (index_name))
                yield (json.dumps(record, default=str))

es_response = elastic_client.bulk(to_elastic_json(df, INDEX_name))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handling" the duplicates? Taking just the first/last occurrence? What's the unique field anchor?

Comment: hello @jzzfs, i mean using the id of data frame as the  _id of elasticsearch

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to do. I'll write an answer and we'll discuss there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

Yes, ES will update the doc w/ a new `_version` number if you ingest a doc w/ an already existing `_id`:

Here's how to do it:

```
def to_elastic_json(df, index_name):
    import json
    for record in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
        yield ('{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s", "_id": "%s"}}'% (index_name, str(record['id'])))
        yield (json.dumps(record, default=str))
```

Verify by calling

```
GET INDEX_NAME/_search?version=true
```

and looking for the `_version` attribute.

---

ORIGINAL

Why not let ES auto-generate the `_id` and you keep your own `id` separate. That way, you can then write a script to find docs with the same `id` and only keep the 'correct' docs?

E.g.:

2 dupes & one unique

```
POST df/_doc
{
  "doc_id": 0,
  "email_addr": "e@f.com",
  "timestamp": 10
}

POST df/_doc
{
  "doc_id": 0,
  "email_addr": "a@b.com",
  "timestamp": 100
}

POST df/_doc
{
  "doc_id": 1,
  "email_addr": "a@e.com"
}
```

Then finding uniques and including, arbitrarily, just the 'most recent' one:

```
GET df/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "scripted_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 1000,
        "field": "doc_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_agg": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
...
"aggregations" : {
    "scripted_terms" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 0,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "top_hits_agg" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "df",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Ev635HEBW-D5QnrWDjzH",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "doc_id" : 0,
                    "email_addr" : "a@b.com",
                    "timestamp" : 100
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    100
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ jzzfs, i would like to avoid check if document exists before inserting data, i would like to delegate this task to elasticseach and i read in the docs that if you set your dataframe id as the _id elasticsearch never insert a duplicate, it just updates the existing one.

Comment: That's right. Will update my answer to explain it more.